# Docker: Setting up a GUI in a Docker Container on a Raspberry Pi

Tags: user-interface, raspberry-pi, docker

I've been playing around with Docker in the past few weeks and currently I'm trying to set up a project.

I'm running a Raspberry Pi with Docker installed. I want to set up a container and use RDP to connect to a remote host.

I have tried working with Xorg (LXDE) and tried starting my graphical environment with startx but that doesn't seem to work. After some googling I found out that you cannot run startx on a virtualized device since startx will look after the graphics card and a virtual machine does not have that.

In order for my RDP to work I need a GUI that runs in a Docker container and uses the ARM architecture.

Has anyone else had any experience with this? 
All help is appreciated!

Thanks
Vincentvo

Comment: Have a look at this Dockerfile, as xrdp is close to RDP, https://registry.hub.docker.com/u/kxes/ubuntu-xrdp-base/dockerfile/ and I suppose you have noticed this distribution for Rasp (that includes RDP) http://rpitc.blogspot.fr/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding --privileged to my docker run command fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just curious, but are you 100% tied to RDP?  If you use VNC, you could just use the ubuntu ARM distro and then VNC into it.  IF you are using a windows machine, superVNC should work for you.

There are even VNC clients for android.   Come to think of it, you might be able to use Chrome RDP as well, havent tried that though.

Comment: I'm not tied to rdesktop but from what I've heard and read it seems that VNC causes a lot more overhead than rdesktop... I could be wrong though since I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: yeah, meant UltraVNC.  Been a while since I've used it, forgot the name.